# adding an intent to detect an Entity List on Luis

Tags: c#, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I created an entity list on luis to have a collection of bad words, I then created an intent named Bad. After that I started adding some bad words as utterance on my Bad Intent, my question is that do I have to again add all those bad words that i already created on my entity list, this time as an utterance under the Bad Intent for luis to capture all the bad words the user might use? am I using the entity list correctly? my understanding is that luis can already capture all the bad words that was already added to the list and tag it as Bad luis intent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. After you make the `bad` list entity, the occurrences in any intent will be marked as `bad`. Remember, that list entity looks for an exact match with its items. If you want to make something more cognitive, consider using `phrase lists`. On the other hand, you can create a normal `bad` entity and mark the utterances by yourself. It's ok to do that, but remember, that this will focus more on linguistics and positions of the words in sentences, for ex:

`Stop the [da*n] train, CJ` - you mark it as `bad`

and

`Stop the [nice] train, CJ` - it's also an adjective :/

May be identified in a similar way.